# If an SSD overheats will it shut itself off?

Tags: ssd, overheating

I recently got an OCZ Vertex 4 SSD.  I knew they had very poor reputation when I bought it, but I wanted to get a drive with very high IOPS so I bought it anyway.

Sometimes when the drive is under heavy use such as playing video games it disconnects from the computer.  I have noticed that it is extremely warm when it does this.

Is this a built in safety feature, or do I have a bad drive?

Comment: I cannot find any specifications that say it does, probably defective.

Comment: @Moab: I wouldn't assume that. It's not a particularly tough feature to add. Still, my bet would be repeated ECC (Error Correction Code) failures. All flash drives use those (as do harddisks, BTW). There's already a mechanism to detect and deal with them. Disconnecting would be just the last action in the chain of recovery steps.

Comment: @MSalters I did not assume, I said I could not find any documentation to support it. "probably" is not an assumption, but an opinion until someone can change it with documentation that says otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

- Haven't seen anybody complaining about heating problems on the Vertex 4. You did mention it gets warm, but warm as in what temperature? If it's between `35°C - 50°C`, then I guess the temperature is fine.
- They have fixed some known issues on the firmware, and since you have a problem, please try upgrading the firmware from [here](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/OCZ_Vertex_3,_Vertex_3_Max_IOPS,_Agility_3,_Solid_3,_RevoDrive_3,_RevoDrive_3_X2_and_Synapse_/).
- You should also consider using a SSD diagnostic tool to check your OCZ disk. There are many free tools on the web. If there are issues, it will point them out to you.
- Some guys on the OCZ community have developed some tools for the SSD. You can get some help [here](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?51522-SSD-Tweaking-and-Diagnostics-Tools) too.
- You may also want to consider diagnosing your OS, or put the drive onto another computer to see if the problem persists.
- As a last resort you will have get help from OCZ support.